# Backbone - call function of one layout from different layout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have 2 layouts as follows and layout 2 has function called 'abc' and i am setting a region content in that layout. I need to update the layout2 region content from a function call from layout 1.
And i am using the below code to do that. it is perfectly calling the function but the view is not getting refreshed after that. Please let me know how to trigger the function properly and update the content

```
 module.layout1= Marionette.Layout.extend ({
   var layout = new module.layout2();
            layout.abc();
});

 module.layout2= Marionette.Layout.extend ({

function abc()
{
regionA.show(view);
}

});
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Marionette Reqion's 'show' function rerenders view if it's different from one you already have in region. But you can force rerendering using following way:

```
regionA.show(view, { forceShow: true });
```